# NoClassDefFoundError and ExceptionInInitializerError When a working project in maven is converted to gradle using gradle init

Tags: java, maven, gradle

So I had a serenity test automation project in Maven and I wanted it to be converted it to gradle. As fate would have it, I tried to use

> gradle init

in the folder where maven pom xml is kept. Now when I try to run the project via gradle using

> gradle clean test aggregate

whole world is collapsing and giving me error such as ExceptionInInitializerError and NoClassDefFoundError.

Kindly help this poor programmar.

Comment: Please read the [Gradle Migration Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html). `gradle init` will give you a starting point but I never saw this working without long comparing sessions of dependencies and build artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All the dependencies are obviously included in the build.gradle file, otherwise it will give me compile time error. The errors I am getting are run time.

Comment: Well, you have runtime and compile denpendencies and you need both of cause. Therefore, you have to look and compare your runtime dependencies.